# Best practice for dying when it's determined a JS plugin didn't receive a required parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, raphael

I'm writing a JavaScript plugin that receives a set of settings, some required, some not.  It's actually a plugin for Raphael.js but this question extends to jQuery plugins too.

My code looks something like the following:

```
jQuery.fn.myplugin = function (settings) { 
    settings = settings || {};
    var reqParam1= settings.requiredParameter1 || return; //Or throw? //Or ... ?

    /* More code */
}
```

If I determine that the plugin didn't receive all the required settings, what course of action should I take?  The obvious and most conservative choice is to `throw` but what about in the case where the plugin functioning isn't 'essential'?  By not 'essential' I mean purely an aesthetic enhancement or less-than-critical to the rest of the page.  In this case could it be correct to die silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw on mandatory parameters, if it means your plugin cannot function (but try to keep mandatory parameters to a minimum), and use defaults for everything else.

```
jQuery.fn.myplugin = function (settings) { 
    settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myplugin.defaults, settings);
    if(!settings.requiredParameter1) throw "Missing requiredParameter1";

    /* More code */
}

jQuery.fn.myplugin.defaults = {
  optionalParameter1: true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `throw` in case of fatal problems like missing mandatory parameters. Deciding whether this plugin's functionality is 'essential' or not is the caller's responsbility. So you can wrap the plugin call in try .. catch block and log the message in the catch block.

```
try {
    $.myplugin( ... );
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('Feature not enabled');
}
```